# WCF Custom class return error

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I got error when try to return the custom class back to the user. When the it thrown exception it should return the custom class but I unable to do it.

```
Public Function LoginRequest(ByVal obj As LoginRequest) As LoginResponse Implements ITTMSService.LoginRequest

    Dim ReaderID As String
    Dim InternalID As String
    Dim TransRefDateTime As String
    Dim Operator as String 
    Dim Balance As String
    Dim Cryptogram As String
    Dim ResponseCode As String
    Dim ResponseMsg As String

    Dim aLoginResponse As New LoginResponse
    Dim aLoginResponseErr As New LoginResponseEx

    Dim response = ws2.login(ReaderID, InternalID, TransRef, TransRefDateTime, [Operator], Balance, Cryptogram, ResponseCode, ResponseMsg)

    If ResponseCode = "00" Then
        With aLoginResponse
            .ReaderID = ReaderID
            .Cryptogram = Cryptogram
            .TransDateTime = TransRefDateTime
            .ResponseCode = ResponseCode
        End With

        Return aLoginResponse
    Else
        With aLoginResponseErr
            .ReaderID = ReaderID
            .Cryptogram = Cryptogram
            .TransDateTime = TransRefDateTime
            .ResponseCode = ResponseCode
            .ResponseMsg = ResponseMsg
        End With

        Return aLoginResponseErr
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

The class:

```
#Region "LoginResponse"
<DataContract([Namespace]:="")>
Public Class LoginResponse
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property TerminalID As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ReaderID As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property TransRef As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property TransDateTime As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Timeout As Integer
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ResponseCode As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Cryptogram As String
End Class
#End Region

#Region "LoginResponseEx"
<DataContract([Namespace]:="")>
Public Class LoginResponseEx : Inherits LoginResponse
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ResponseMsg As String
End Class
#End Region
```

I got error when return the LoginResponseErr class. Please hielp. Thanks

```
Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are successfully connecting to the service. Can you retrieve a return value from a simple GetData method?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the [`KnownType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on the `LoginResponseEx` class.

```
<DataContract(), KnownType(GetType(LoginResponse))>
Public Class LoginResponseEx : Inherits LoginResponse
   ...
End Class
```

Comment: The error message you provided after I wrote my answer does not indicate a problem with the response. Can you connect to the service at all and for example get an `int` from a simple method? If not, you have a general problem in your WCF configuration. You will, however, still need the `KnownType` attribute to return a subclass of `LoginResponse`, so while my answer does not solve the immediate problem, it will be the solution to further problems arising as soon as you can connect to the service.